# R: How do I efficiently reference / calculate from a separate data frame using dplyr mutate?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data-science

Hello stack**overflow** community,

Given a data frame of two columns, points of latitude and longitude (dfLatLon), I’d like to add a third column that looks up the number of crimes in a ~0.1 mile radius from a separate data frame with a list of crimes in the city of Denver (dfCrimes).

The solution below works (which I found searching stackoverflow, thank you!), but I have a hunch it’s inefficient, so I’d like to improve it if possible.

I’ve attempted to make this code reproducible (I’ve read enough posts to know that’s a must), but you will have to go to one of the sites below to download the crime data, which is ~74MB.  Hope this isn’t an issue.  Alternatively, you can use the other method below (uncomment it, comment the other), which doesn’t require you to download the file separately and is thus perhaps more reproducible, but I found it to be much slower (336 sec vs. 16 sec to load CSV).

Crime Web Page:  http://data.denvergov.org/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-crime

Direct Link to the Data:  http://data.denvergov.org/download/gis/crime/csv/crime.csv

```
# Initialization Stuff
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
set.seed(77)  #In honor of Red Grange … Go Illini!

#Set Working Directory
#setwd("INSERT YOUR WD HERE, LOCATION OF CRIME DATA")

#Load Crime Data
dfCrimes <- read.csv("crime.csv")

#Alternate method to obtain file, no separate download or setting working directory required, but MUCH slower.
#dfCrimes <- read.csv("http://data.denvergov.org/download/gis/crime/csv/crime.csv")

#Set Degrees per Mile Constants
cstDegPerMileLat <- 0.01450737744
cstDegPerMileLon <- 0.01882547865

#Create Lats & Lons Data Frame (a grid of ~0.1mi centers in a square around Denver)
vecLat <- seq(39.6098, 39.9146, cstDegPerMileLat * 0.1)
vecLon <- seq(-105.1100, -104.5987, cstDegPerMileLon * 0.1)
dfLatLon <- expand.grid(vecLat, vecLon)
colnames(dfLatLon) <- c("lat","lon")

#Add 3rd Column
#THIS IS THE PART THAT I THINK CAN BE MORE EFFICIENT … PLEASE HELP!
system.time(dfLatLon <- dfLatLon %>% rowwise %>% mutate(newcol = sum( dfCrimes$IS_CRIME [  ((dfCrimes$GEO_LAT - lat)*(1/cstDegPerMileLat))^2 + ((dfCrimes$GEO_LON - lon)*(1/cstDegPerMileLon))^2 < 0.1^2 ])) )

#Wrapped formula above in system.time to measure efficiency.
#At its core, the formula above is just the basic formula for a circle, x^2 + y^2 = r^2, with adjustments to convert degrees of lat/lon to miles.
```

This took 747 seconds (~12 minutes) to run and used only 1 processor, which is way better than the ~30 min it took to run in Excel using all 4 processors.  I realize 12 minutes isn’t prohibitively long, but if I scale this solution to larger problems, it’ll matter more.

Also, I’m running R Studio in a Windows 10 OS.

Here are my specific questions:

1. Are there ways of using dplyr to run this more efficiently?  I’ve read it’s super-efficient for this kind of problem.  I suspect rowwise is a performance killer (perhaps it’s not vectorized; could it be?), but I’ve not been able to get it to run without using rowwise.

1a. Should I convert from data frames to data.tables?

1b. How can I use multiple processors to increase speed?  Seems a waste to let 3 processor cores sit idle.

1c. Should I be using some kind of join or group_by?  I don’t think so because there’s not a direct reference to exact lat’s and lon’s, but I’m open to this possibility if that’s the right (faster) answer.

If there’s a better way to tackle this problem without dplyr, I’d like to see it, but I’d also like to see a solution in dplyr just so I can learn it better.

Finally, please note I’m doing this analysis for the sake of learning R and data science (I don’t work for the City of Denver), and am exploring larger data sets to improve my skills.  I’m a beginner to R and data science, but I’ve been an analyst doing some fairly sophisticated analyses in Excel for years.  I know Excel’s limitations, and am thus fascinated by the potential of R, data science, and machine learning.

This is my first post, so hopefully I’ve covered everything.  Please let me know in the comments if I’m missing something, posted in the wrong spot, violated some rule, etc.

Thanks so much for your help!!!

p.s., I realize my lats and lons aren’t evenly spaced, and the degrees of lat/lon per mile aren’t uniform either, both due to convergence toward the north pole and Earth’s not-quite-spherical shape.  I’m ignoring this for now.  I just want to know how to efficiently reference an ‘outside’ data frame using dplyr.

p.p.s., Eventually I plan to make a predictive model from this data, likely experimenting using caret, but for now I’m trying to improve my pre-processing skills.

Comment: Since you loaded doParallel, why not use `foreach` and `%dopar%` instead of `rowwise`? Alternatively, you could also try running `mclapply` to apply each row of lat, lon onto the calculation of crime.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So that takes care of the parallel processing bit.  To clarify your suggestion, can `foreach` and `%dopar%` be run within dplyr? Or should I just parse each row individually (e.g., for each row, calculate X).  And is `foreach` efficient?  I thought it generally wasn't, but perhaps I'm mistaken...again, I'm new to this.

And does anyone have any thoughts about a vectorized approach, and/or other ways to maximize dplyr efficiency?

Thanks!!